# 英語が残っている: レビュー履歴へのリンクと、レビュー待ちがない場合のアラート

Tags: バグ, 完了, 翻訳, 英語

### レビュー|推奨される編集内容

URL: https://ja.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/history

[image: my review history]

### レビュー|再オープン票

URL:  
https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/review/close  
https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/review/reopen

[image: This queue has been cleared!]

Comment: 'My review history'は開発者が必要です。下記のレビューは翻訳を登録しました。できれば、1つのポストに1つの問題をできれば、管理しやすくなりますが、これの方がentoさんにとって簡単なら、別に進んでください。

Comment: 了解です。あまり手間はかわらないので、問題ごとにポストを分けるようにしますね。

Comment: タグはstatus-completedとなってますが、現在（また？）英語になってます。

Answer (score 1):

> my review history

レビュー履歴

> This queue has been cleared! If you're looking for more to review, view all review queues. 
>   Want to get back to the questions? Return to the スタック・オーバーフローMeta homepage.

もうこのカテゴリにはレビュー待ちの投稿はありません！もっとレビューしますか？他のレビューカテゴリをチェックしてみてください。それともスタック・オーバーフローMetaのトップページに戻ってQ&Aを再開しますか？